# Shopping Cart Libraries for Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, paypal, shopping-cart, accounts, ups

currently i am designing a shopping cart in Zend Framework.
I decided to write code for user/roles/product catalog from scratch which i have already done and tested. But for other things i need you guys to guide me which are the best classes/libraries to build this system system.

I need following functionality as

1. Order
2. Inventory
3. Accounts
4. Paypal Integration
5. UPS/USPS/Fedex Integration.

and thanks for your time.

Note: I have already gone through magento modules, its bit difficult to extract from it what i need, so it will be last resort for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External vendors such as Paypal or Fedex has guides on their sites.

Take a look like other do this:

- Magento Commerce
- Opencart
- PrestaShop
- OsCommerce
- Zen Cart
- Digistore
- CREloaded
- Zeuscart
- ShopperPress

I'm surprised it's difficult to extract. Magento architecture isn't very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Forget trying to "extract it yourself". Here's an actual tutorial that shows you how to use the Zend Framework and PayPal API calls.

http://www.alexventure.com/.../zend-framework-and-the-paypal-api-part-1-of-2/

Comment: +1 Thanks bro, its a good resource. I will surly use it when i will be in need.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework doesn't have libraries, it's a framework which means all the stuff you need for the libraries and shopping cart is there... you'll just have to write them yourself